# interpolating ruby in JavaScript unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, ruby, haml

I have source code for an app that uses Ember,CoffeeScript, Haml with Rails. In the layout file, it initiates the app with this code, which has a current_user_json helper method written in Ruby

```
:javascript
    App.ready = function() {
      App.initApp(jQuery.parseJSON('#{current_user_json}'))
    }
```

Trying to recreate the app with erb and JavaScript, I get an unexpected token error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token #
```

If I do the following

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 App.ready = function() {
      App.initApp(jQuery.parseJSON('#{ current_user_json}'));
    }
  </script>
```

Why is that token unexpected and how can I avoid that error?

Comment: `#{ variable }` interpolation is only for HAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if it's not working for you in HAML or not based on your question.  I would assume it is, because I use that same method as well and it works fine.

As for ERB, I don't personally use it but I don't think you can just drop a string in like that, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  App.ready = function() {
    App.initApp(jQuery.parseJSON('<%= current_user_json %>'));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to double quotes.

`App.initApp(jQuery.parseJSON("#{ current_user_json}"));`